# Working with C# Object on Disk

Tags: c#, serialization, object

I understand how serialization works and was wondering if there is a way to store an object on the disk and work with the object and save the changes.

I am trying to avoid directly doing this:

1. Opening the file
2. Deserializing the object
3. Changing the object
4. Serializing the changes by overwriting the old file

Is there a class that allows a file to be used as an object store, namely List<object> and working with it directly on the disk without having to complete the above processes?

Comment: because it's inefficient.... Try loading and deserializing 400mb of data each time just to add one object to a list.

Comment: Even if you managed to do that, that's what would happen behind the scenes as that's how a computer works

Comment: If it is a list, why not use a db?

Comment: @Oskar More or less so, however there are things like Memory Mapped files that allow you to use a hybrid approach. Also, think of a database, do you think it loads an entire 100GB table in memory just to add a row? I don't think so....

Comment: @Oskar it's a list of .net objects, they can't be stored in a db without extensive amount of work because they are not all of the same type.

Comment: I must've missed the last part about you were storing lists. Storing a single object would most likely have you read it in

Comment: @Jeff you can store the serialized bits in the db

Comment: Is storing it as an XML file not an option because of size?

Comment: It isn't worth storing it in a DB because they are just temporary objects. I have a service that is more or less a Queue of tasks, however, if the computer loses power I do not want to lose the tasks.

Comment: It's probably the easiest way to do it and also the fastest

Comment: In that case I would use SQLite. I have used it in the past to store temporary objects with ease of using SQL statements. It is embedded, so no overheads of a typical database (like background services etc).

Comment: DBAs aren't going to want this in a database.

Comment: @Jeffrey just use a hidden SQLite database, the DBAs won't even know about it :)

Comment: alright will look into it, thanks oskar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [DB4O](http://developer.db4o.com/Home.aspx). It seems to be a solution for your requirements.

Comment: This looks pretty awesome! Thanks Vijay!

Comment: Cheers! SQLite could have helped you too (I added that suggestion as a comment to your original post.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe there is an out of the box solution for this. Just search on how to save arbitrary data in a file, and think up your own format.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at something like [ESE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine) which comes with Windows. [There is a managed interface for it](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ManagedEsentDocumentation). Never used it though.

Either that or use a lightweight database e.g. SQLite, since effectively, if you want to add, remove and modify data on the disk, some kind of database is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

[Objectivity](http://www.objectivity.com/products/objectivitydb/) is another alternative. It supports computing across vast distributed networks or embedded in stand-alone devices that simply must not fail, enables persistent object management, virtually instantaneous traversal of complex, many-to-many relationships and graphs, and much more.